# Two parameter sets for Swift's NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nstimer

I'm currently learning Swift for the first time, and am having some headaches as the latest version was apparently just released.

Many tutorials are teaching students how to use NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval, yet the parameters they show are always different than the newest version.  They're showing:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(<interval>,target: <target>,selector:<selector>,userInfo:<userInfo>,repeats:<bool>);
```

However, the latest version is showing:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(<NSTimeInterval>, invocation: <NSInvocation>, repeats: <bool>)
```

I'm not originally C developer, so without any tuts on this change it's hard for me to understand what happening.  I believe I need to set the selector and target in the invocation object (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/), however, I think that's much further along in my studies.

So my question is, how can I get this basic functionality to work?  I don't know how to set an invocation, and the first version returns an error.

Comment: I don't quite see what your actual question is?

Comment: Those are two different methods. You can use either one.

Comment: Question added, though it was pretty obvious.  Others got it.  I don't think it was worth a down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that you can't use the rendition with the `selector` parameter anymore. You can. These are simply two different renditions of `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` and they've both been around since iOS 2.0.

So, go ahead and use the rendition with the `selector` parameter. Don't worry about the `invocation` rendition.